# How to write an algorithm for numerical solution of Stokes equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider $$\displaystyle \begin{cases}
   -\triangle \bf{u} + \operatorname{grad} p = \bf{f} & D = [0,1]^2\\
   \operatorname{div}\bf{u} = 0\\
   \int_{D} p(x,y) dxdy = 0\\
   \bf{u}\big|_{\Omega} = 0 \
 \end{cases}$$, where $\bf{u}$ $= (v(x,y),w(x,y))$, $p(x,y)$ and $\bf{f}$ $= (f^1(x,y),f^2(x,y))$. $\bf{u}$ and $p(x,y)$ are needed to be found.

Let $h_xN = 1$, $h_y M = 1.$
We want to find numerical approximation for given task. I've tried to use MAC-scheme([about MAC-scheme](https://www.math.uci.edu/~chenlong/226/MACStokes.pdf)). Briefly : we consider discrete approximation in middle points of uniform grid.

I've considered this grid:

$\bar{D}_1 = \{x_{i,j} = ((i -1/2)h_x,jh_y)  : i = 0\dots N, j = 0 \dots M\}$

$\bar{D}_2 = \{x_{i,j} = (h_x,(j - 1/2)h_y)  : i = 0\dots N, j = 0 \dots M\}$

$\bar{D}_3 = \{x_{i,j} = (h_x,jh_y)  : i = 0\dots N - 1, j = 0 \dots M - 1\}$

Now I know that difference scheme for this problem is:

$$\displaystyle \begin{cases}
\ \frac{v_{i+1,j} - 2v_{i,j}+v_{i-1,j}}{h_x^2} +\frac{v_{i,j+1} - 2v_{i,j}+v_{i,j-1}}{h_y^2} - \frac{p_{i,j} - p_{i-1,j}}{h_x} = -f^1_{i,j}\\
\frac{w_{i+1,j} - 2w_{i,j}+w_{i-1,j}}{h_x^2} +\frac{w_{i,j+1} - 2w_{i,j}+w_{i,j-1}}{h_y^2} - \frac{p_{i,j} - p_{i,j-1}}{h_y} = -f^2_{i,j}\\
\ \frac{v_{i+1,j} - v_{i,j}}{h_x} + \frac{w_{i,j+1} - w_{i,j}}{h_y} = 0
\end{cases}.$$

Also we know that $v_{0,j} = v_{i,0} = v_{i,M} = v_{N,j} = w_{0,j} = w_{i,0} = w_{i,M} = w_{N,j} = 0$

$N.B.$ we may consider it like 
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
\ A & B\\
\ B^\top & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 
\ \bf{u}\\
p
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 
\ \bf{f}\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
.$$ So as *timur* said, we can find inverse matrix. But that's not easier task, I think. Because this matrix won't be tridiagonal matrix.

*Edited :*

I've read about Uzawa's algorithm. But I don't understand how can we use it here. Because $u$ should be vector for this. But how can we get exact form of $A$ and $B$ for this.

Comment: Usually you start the iteration for some guessed value on the grid (with the boundary conditions fixed), and then iterate over the grid.

Comment: Form a matrix and invert it.

Comment: @timur I thought about so, but I guess it will take a lot of calculations. Even if $Lu = f$ will have good matrix.

Comment: @Paul so I must approximate some initial state?

Comment: That's how it is done in practice. Especially since your matrix will be indefinite. You can use a standard linear algebra library.

Comment: @timur as I understand it calls Uzawas iteration. I will try to construct this matrix.

Comment: @timur am I right that $A$ will be $2N \times 2N$ ?

Comment: Yes, you can use Uzawa. What programming language are you using? For example, in Python, you have NumPy and SciPy which have everything already implemented.

Comment: @timur, i need to check it by my own.